# Spark SQL - better way to group by field

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

For example if i have the payments data [ 30 to 40 columns in a DataFrame] and the volume of data is around 4 Million [not huge though]. But need to do lot of[25 to 30] different calculations using groupBy and agg operations on DF.

Since we are going to use the same DF for different calculations, we are using `cache()`.

Example DF:

```
country transactions
IN      1001
IN      1002
UK      1003
UK      1004
```

Currently what i am doing is

```
df.groupBy("country").agg(countDisinct(transactions)) as txncnt)
```

My question is what are other ways i can achieve the same [may be better way of grouping data in Spark SQL DataFrame], can we do something like `reduceByKey or AggregateByKey [RDD operations]?`

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using groupBy and do operations on the data you probably should use a reduceByKey directly. Each executor will then just send the result of his calculations.

Try to create a DF with a group calculations that you can use for all of your 20 calculations and cache it...

Comment: What if i have to groupBy more than one fields on a DF?